# C++ Calendar Alignment Issue

Tags: c++, calendar

[image: Here is what it should look like]

I am having trouble aligning the first day of the month with the right weekday. The calendar is going to be for this year so January first will be on Friday but I cant seem to get any of firsts of each month off of the left side. I tried to change the `setw` but its not working for some reason.

[image: Here is what mine looks like now]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void month(int days, int day)
{
    int i;
    string weekDays[7] = { " Sun ", " Mon ", " Tue ", " Wed ", " Thu ", " Fri ", " Sat " };

    cout << endl << "  " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(1) << "  " << weekDays[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "  " << endl;

   
    int firstDay = day - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
    {
        cout  << setw(5) << " " << setw(2) << i;
      
        if ((i + firstDay - 1) % 7 == 0)
        {  
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    
    int i, day = 1;
    
    int yearly[12][2] = { {1,31},{2,28},{3,31},{4,30},{5,31},{6,30},{7,31},{8,31},{9,30},{10,31},{11,30},{12,31} };

    string months[] = { "January","February","March","April", "May", "June","July",
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << " -------------------- "<<months[i] << " -------------------- "<< endl;
        month(yearly[i][1], day);

        if (day == 7)
        {
            day = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            day = day + 1;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the output of your program, as well as the desired output.

Comment: @cigien just edited the post

Comment: Don't you need to account for which day the previous month ended? You don't appear to be doing that.

Comment: @cigien the yearly array is the number of the month and the last day

Comment: This is probably something you should step through with a debugger. In addition, you might want to change the explicit spaces to something visible, to make it easier for you to interpret your output. I see four lines that output spaces; three with two spaces each, and one with one space (ignoring the effects of `setw`). I might change those to `"--"`, `"=="`, `"^^"`, and `"."` so you can see where the output of each line ends up.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have identified the problem!
You are not dealing with the spaces of the first day of every month here so what you have to do adjust the spaces for the first day of every month separately!
like this:
[just dealing with the spaces of first day of every month outside the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRvNg.png)

It will give the output like this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QETQD.png)

But I was not able to format the weeks properly here is the complete code that I used you can edit this piece of code accordingly!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int month(int days, int day)
{
    int i;
    string weekDays[7] = { " Sun ", " Mon ", " Tue ", " Wed ", " Thu ", " Fri ", " Sat " };

    cout << endl << "  " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(2) << "  " << weekDays[i];
    }
    cout << endl << "  " << endl;

   //printing first day and the rest of the month in the loop!
    int firstDay = day; 
     cout  << setw( (5*firstDay) + 10) << " " << setw(2) <<"1";

    for (int i = 2; i <= days; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(5)<<" "<<setw(2) << i;
        firstDay++;
        /*if ((i + firstDay - 1) % 7 == 0)
        {  
            cout << endl;
        }*/
        if(firstDay % 7 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
            firstDay=0;
        }
    }
    return firstDay;
}
int main(){
    
    //January 1st is friday so passing the day as 6 since its the sixth element in your output
    int i, day = 6;
    
    int yearly[12][2] = { {1,31},{2,28},{3,31},{4,30},{5,31},{6,30},{7,31},{8,31},{9,30},{10,31},{11,30},{12,31} };

    string months[] = { "January","February","March","April", "May", "June","July",
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << " -------------------- "<<months[i] << " -------------------- "<< endl;
        day= month(yearly[i][1], day);

        if(day == 0)
        day++;
       

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```